# Sum not working when using with, sum, group by, order by and from

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have code that gets columns from two different tables in order to show customer IDs and sum all the products they used for the duration of their subscription. However the code is not summing so for a table like this, I want the output to be the same columns except product usage is summed by product and master_id.

| master_id | product | product_usage | id | billing_period_start_date | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apples | 2 | 1 | January 1 | January 1 |
| 1 | apples | 5 | 1 | February 1 | January 1 |
| 1 | oranges | 3 | 1 | January 1 | January 1 |
| 2 | oranges | 1 | 2 | January 1 | January 1 |
| 2 | oranges | 7 | 2 | February 1 | January 1 |
| 2 | apples | 2 | 2 | January 1 | January 1 |

Output

| master_id | product | product_usage | id | billing_period_start_date | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apples | 7 | 1 | January 1 | January 1 |
| 1 | oranges | 3 | 1 | January 1 | January 1 |
| 2 | oranges | 8 | 2 | January 1 | January 1 |
| 2 | apples | 2 | 2 | January 1 | January 1 |

but my code is not doing the sum and is returning everything separately like the first table. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
with results as 

(select bill.master_id, 
bill.product, 
sum(bill.product_usage), 
subscription.id,
bill.billing_period_start_date,
subscription.start_date, 



from 
bill, 
subscription

where bill.master_id = subscription.id
and master_id in ('1',
'2',
'3',
'4',
'5',)
and billing_period_start_date >= start_date
group by master_id, product, id, billing_period_start_date, start_date
order by master_id
)


select * from results
```

Comment: it does what it should, at least one of the columns is different

Comment: What data types are `billing_period_start_date` and `start_date`

Comment: one more question - why do you need cte if you do `select * from results`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think they are dates

Comment: @Andronicus what is cte? I am new to sql so I'm not quite sure if I'm being redundant there

Comment: @PN567890 `with`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
select 
bi.master_id, 
bi.product, 
su.id,
bi.billing_period_start_date,
su.start_date,
sum(bi.product_usage)

from 
bill bi, 
subscription su

where 
bi.master_id = su.id and bi.master_id in ('1','2','3','4','5') and bi.billing_period_start_date >= su.start_date
group by 
bi.master_id, 
bi.product, 
su.id,
bi.billing_period_start_date,
su.start_date
order by bi.master_id;
```

Comment: did you just change the ordering of columns? :D

Comment: no, that was for beautifying reasons, I also added the table prefixes to the fields in the group by clause.

Comment: I see, hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work

Comment: I modified the script, you didn`t have table prefixes in the where clause. try it now.

Comment: I added prefixes like you did. It's still not summing.

Comment: maybe... now? you had a ';' missing at the end of the order by clause and a stray comma in the in ('1','2','3','4','5',)

Comment: Thanks for noticing the comma. I'm getting a syntax error when I add the ; at the end of order by and it's returning the original result without the ;

Comment: @Andronicus I don't see your comment on why it won't work. Is it because I'm using with?

Comment: @PN567890 no, the first one. The query works properly, you're expecting a wrong output if you want to group by all these columns